# Select entries that include a certain number of words in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, select

I have some data like this:

```
one two
one two three
one
one two
```

and I would like to select, for example, all the entries that include two words. Is it possible to do this in Sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableName
WHERE
    length(columnName) = length(replace(columnName, ' ', '')) + 1;
```

Comment: Very smart solution, I'll give that a try.